# datediff weird stuff - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

TEST:

```
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190105 23:01:11.821')
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190106 23:01:11.821')
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190107 23:01:11.821')
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190108 23:01:11.821')
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190109 23:01:11.821')
    select datediff(week, '20190104 23:01:11.821', '20190113 23:01:11.821')
```

This returns

```
    0
    1
    1
    1
    2
```

I see common sense only in the 1st return value.
What is going on?
E.g. how come the last one returns 2 weeks?! 
How come the others return what they return?

Comment: Rather than assume what seems to be common sense, consult the [datediff documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql): "This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate."

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Datediff counts how often a border is crossed.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '20190104 23:01:11.821')
,       DATEPART(WEEK, '20190106 23:01:11.821')
```

Returns

```
1   2
```

So one week border was crossed, so datediff returns 1.

Answer (score 3):

The `datediff()` function returns number of date part boundaries between two dates.

So, `datediff(year, '2018-12-31', '2020-01-01')` will return "2", because there are two year boundaries.

Week boundaries occur on Saturday night/Sunday morning.  There are two Saturday nights, so you get two weeks.

If you want a closer approximation of the number of weeks, use `day` and divide by 7.

Answer (score -2):

Did you identify what is the first day of the week?

you can consult it in the following way indicating a date and you will know in what position of the week it is.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

for example and according to your dates, if the day of the week was Sunday, "I would be right".